# storing a string into an array causes an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: java

```
int x = 0;
String[] QEquivalent = {};

String s = sc.nextLine();
String[] question2 = s.split(" ");

for (int i = 0; i < question2.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(question2[i]);
    x++;
}                                                                   //debug
System.out.println(x);

String s2 = sc2.nextLine();
String[] Answer = s2.split(" ");

for (int c = 0; c < Answer.length; c++) {
    System.out.println(Answer[c]);
}                                                                   //debug
int y;

String u = sn.nextLine();
String[] t = u.split(" ");
for (y = 0; y < question2.length; y++) {
    for (int w = 0; w < t.length; w++) {
        if (t[w].equals(question2[y])) {
            QEquivalent[y] = "ADJ";
            System.out.println(QEquivalent[y]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

this is the line of codes that I have as of now. when a string in question2 is found in String[] t, it should store the string "ADJ" in String[] QEquivalent. I can't seem to fix the error. can someone please help me?

Comment: The variables in Java should start with a `lowercase`. Like `Answer` and `QEquivalent`.

Comment: The `String[]` `QEquivalent` is an empty array - obviously any attempt to access its members by index will result in an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating an empty array here:

```
String[] QEquivalent = {};
```

So, any index you try to access will be out of bounds. You should creating an array using a fixed size.

Or, you can better use an `ArrayList` instead, which can dynamically grow in size:

```
List<String> qEquivalent = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and then add elements using:

```
qEquivalent.add("ADJ");
```

And please follow Java Naming conventions. Variable names should start with lowercase letters.

Comment: should I remove ={} ?

Comment: @user2610661. Either you create an array of some size, which is still unknown - `String[] qEuivalent = new String[50];`. Or, use an `ArrayList` as I suggest.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks alot! I'm just starting to learn java so thanks again for helping me!

Comment: @user2610661. You're welcome :) And keep consulting Java API, time to time during your learning. You might get something useful for the problem you are solving.

Answer (score 1):

Your array `QEquivalent` is an empty array . It is of length `0` , hence even `QEquivalent[0]` will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

One fix I can see is assign it a length :

```
String[] question2 = s.split(" ");
// Just assign the dimension till which you will iterate finally
// from your code `y < question2.length` it seems it should be question2.length
// Note you are always indexing the array using the outer loop counter  y 
// So even if there are n number of nested loops , assigning the question2.length
// as dimension will work fine , unless there is something subtle you missed 
// in your code
String[] QEquivalent = new String[question2.length];
```

---

Better use any implementation of [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) , like an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

```
List<String> qEquivalent = new ArrayList<String>();
......
if (t[w].equals(question2[y])) {
       qEquivalent.add("ADJ");
       System.out.println(qEquivalent.get(y));
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You create an empty array:

```
String[] QEquivalent = {};
```

and then set some elements at index `y > 0`:

```
QEquivalent[y] = "ADJ";
```

You can either:

- compute the final dimension of the array and be sure to instantiate it: `String[] QEquivalent = new String[SIZE];`
- use a dynamic structure like an `ArrayList`

eg:

```
ArrayList<String> QEquivalent = new ArrayList<QEquivalent>(); 
QEquivalent.add("ADJ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Give some size to the array `String[] QEquivalent = new String[100];`

You statement `String[] QEquivalent = {};` creates an array with zero size.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your `QEquivalent` `array` as an empty `String` `array`.

When you access the index `QEquivalent[y]`, that index doesn't exist, hence the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I strongly suggest you use a `List<String>` instead.

Such as:

```
List<String> qEquivalent = new ArrayList<String>(); // replaces the array declaration and uses Java conventional naming
```

...

```
qEquivalent.add("ADJ"); // replaces the indexing of the array and adds the item
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly QEquivalent variable makes the error.Because when you declare that variable, its length is 0.So declare the variable as with `new` and a size.

Answer (score 0):

Or move it after you split the string into question2 and use:

```
String[] QEquivalent = new String[question2.length];
```

Comment: question2.length won't be enough. There are more elements going to be added. Take a look at the loop which populates array. It is nested, with outer one itself running till `question2.length`.

Comment: @RohitJain But he is indexing it with `j` that is the outer loop counter !

Comment: @RohitJain I disagree.  He uses the loop for (y = 0; y < question2.length; y++) and only assigns QEquivalent[y] = "ADJ";.  So regardless of the inner loop, QEquivalent[y] will never be greater than question2.length.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot. OOPs, didn't notice that. :(